# How do I fetch all children of the parent CKRecord when `userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith(:)` is called?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShareMetadata) {

    let acceptSharesOperation = CKAcceptSharesOperation(shareMetadatas: [cloudKitShareMetadata])
    acceptSharesOperation.perShareCompletionBlock = { metadata, share, error in


            let operation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [cloudKitShareMetadata.rootRecordID])
            operation.perRecordCompletionBlock = { record, _, error in
                //do something with root record
            }

            CloudAssistant.shared.container.sharedCloudDatabase.add(operation)
    }
    acceptSharesOperation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
    CKContainer(identifier: cloudKitShareMetadata.containerIdentifier).add(acceptSharesOperation)
}
```

That way I am able only to download `rootRecord`, but along with this record I associated lot of records using `setParent()`.

Is there a way to fetch them also here?

Comment: I recently figured out how to do this. Do you still need help?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I do